# Problema con Websocket en python

Tags: python, linux, websocket

Tengo un error en python, me encuentro trabajando con webSocket:

```
[Errno 98] Address already in use try
```

Se que esto se origina por que proceso ya está corriendo, como puedo validar esto, para que pase por alto cuando este creado y no genere el error?

Comment: Eso pasa cuando ya hay un proceso escuchando en el puerto. es típico que ocurra cuando tu proceso no termina de forma correcta y no cierra el el socket correctamente y tratas de volver al lanzar el script de nuevo poco después.

Comment: ¿Es un websocket o un socket estándar? A priori no veo el websocket

Comment: Es un websocket en el framework Tornado

Comment: @FJSevilla, tengo claro que el proceso ya está en funcionamiento, cual sería el flujo del funcionamiento de un webSocket?.